# ImageView size is changed when changing the image

Tags: android, android-imageview, scale

I have the problem that I have a layout with an `ImageView`. With `AsyncTask` I load an image from the web. It is a panorama picture. If I start up the `Fragment`, the image I load with `src="@drawable/pano"` is shown perfectly. It has full height and I can scroll through the panorama.

As soon as the new image is loaded into the `ImageView` the imageview rescales so that the height is:

Before the AsyncTask (Image is loaded from drawables...):

[image: before]

And this is after the AsyncTask loaded the image:
[image: after]

Here is my xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/pano" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

AsyncTask Code:

```
public class DownloadPanorama extends
            AsyncTask<ImageView, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView imageView;
        Bitmap bm;

        public DownloadPanorama(ImageView mChart) {
            imageView = mChart;
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(ImageView... imageViews) {
            return download_Image((String) imageView.getTag());
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
        }

        private Bitmap download_Image(String url) {
            Bitmap bm = null;
            try {
                URL aURL = new URL(url);
                URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
                conn.connect();
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
                bis.close();
                is.close();
            return bm;
        }
    }
```

Also happens when not using AsyncTask and only using raw setImageBitmap... So I don't know if I have to change the `scaleType` in my xml file or if I need to set it again after loading a new image?

Comment: Try changing the ImageView's `android:layout_height` to `match_parent`

Comment: Thanks for your help. This does not work :(

Comment: can you post your `AsyncTask` code?

Comment: What is the physical size of both images?

Comment: @Phil I did post it now...

Comment: @RickFalck the image size of both is 1200x400 px...

Comment: Give it to fix dimensions for displaying image. If you have set wrap_content it means if image is small then it display according to it and if it is big then it displays according to it.

Comment: Yes but I also changed the layout_height to match parent etc... Image is always the same size... Only changing...

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

It sounds like from your comments and updated question that you know the size you would like the image to be (1200x400). You have two things you can do to get this size. The first, and recommended, is to replace the line

```
bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
```

with

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.outWidth=1200;
options.outHeight=400;
bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis, new Rect(0,0,0,0), options);
```

The other option is to change your View bounds. In your comments above, it sounds like the bounds might change, so you would have to repeat this each time you loaded a new image of different size:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
params.width = 1200;
params.height = 400;
imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

<del>You need to change

    android:adjustViewBounds="true"

to

    android:adjustViewBounds="false"</del>

Comment: please post your asynctask code - if behavior is different with or without using it, then something is amiss.

Comment: No behavior is the same... It's only different if I load it from src in xml and if I use setImageBitmap...

Answer (score 0):

I would try changing:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

to

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

in your ImageView.

If that doesn't work, you might be able to scale your bitmap:

```
myBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, width, height,true);
```

Comment: This also behaves the same :(